# Why did the query proceeded over query_timeout_threshold are not terminated in Version 0.13.3 of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: timeout, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I read the official guide of Apache IoTDB for this `query_timeout_threshold` configuration, and it said "the system default timeout is 60000 ms, which can be customized by the query_timeout_threshold parameter in the configuration file." Then why are some queries still keep on executing after the execution time exceeds 1 minute, and they are not terminated? When I use Version 0.13.3 of IoTDB to execute complex queries with many filtering conditions, such as command with `in(1,24,4,5,6,7)`, these queries cannot be terminated within 1 minute. Anyone know why this happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Version 1.X of Apache IoTDB, the query execution process is not interruptible everywhere. The system will wait for the execution thread to reach the settled interruptible point before terminating the query, so the set value of `query_timeout_threshold` may be exceeded. If you are still using Version 0.X, you can try to upgrade IoTDB to check this logic.